# Firebase SDK 3.x Linkedin login

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, linkedin-api

I have a problem with the Linkedin login on firebase.
I use a custom token login with firebase, I have the token retrieved from Linkedin, but in Firebase 3 if I call:

`FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken: my_token) { (user, error) in`

I get an error:

`Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17000 "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation., error_name=ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN}`

But I get the token from the session created on LISDKSessionManager.

Here my full function:

```
LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) -> Void in
        guard let session = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session else { return }
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken: session.accessToken.accessTokenValue) { (user, error) in
            //here I get the error
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn OAuth tokens are not automatically usable in Firebase Authentication. They will need to be converted into a Firebase Authentication JWT.

See the page on [minting custom tokens in the Firebase Authentication documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) or the [sample that does this with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth).